git status commands not showing changes in the current branch
I have done changes several changes in different files in the current branch of my repository. But when I am trying to see the changes by running "git status" command then it is now showing me the changes in the files.
I don't know how can I resolve this issue. Can anyone help me with it? Thanks!!

Give us a bit of context: where do you type your commands, which directory does it point to, do you get an error message, anything useful. Because so far, besides bold assumptions we cannot say much.

No more information? Voting to close.

I am assuming you did not initialize the repository, so first you need to use git init to initialize it, this is done only once for each project. This will create a master branch, where you can start adding your files to the repository using git add filename to add one specific file or git add -A to add everything that has been modified in the workspace.

I have already initialized the repo. As I was working on this repo and raised PRs but now I'm working on other stuffs on the same PR.
